# Match all <a> tags except for domains a, b and c

Tags: regex

My Wordpress website was hacked and I have since increased security and changed all info, etc. The hackers have inserted random links to spam websites all through the texts of posts.

I want to find literally all urls in all my posts, but exclude urls containing certain domains. That way I can bulk remove all links that do not point to a short list of domains I normally link to with a plugin.

The plugin requires me to write it a certain way, this works to find all urls in the HTML:

```
[<a.*</a>]
```

I got playing around and ended up with a few versions I tried, but I can't seem to completely figure it out.

`[<a.*</a>(?!domain1.com|domain2.com)]`

`[<a.*(?!domain1.com|domain2.com).*</a>]`

Anyone who can give me a push in the right direction?

---

**Addition:** I'm using this Wordpress plugin: https://www.wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

It's old but works fine otherwise.

Comment: Try this regex: [`<a (?:(?!(?:domain1|domain2)\.).)+</a>`](https://regex101.com/r/i2nGW4/1)

Comment: Did not work sadly, it's still finding <a> tags with the two domains in it.

Comment: What do you see if you use this one as search input string: `<a[^>*]*(domain1|domain2)`

Comment: @s1h4d0w: You can see in linked demo that is **not finding** links with `domain1` or `domain2`.

Comment: It finds no results sadly, thanks for helping tho.

Comment: So either there is an option to negate the end result or there is something wrong with the plugin itself.

Comment: @anubhava It actually seems to work now, I probably messed up somewhere, sorry. But thank you! If you post this as answer I'll mark it.

Comment: ... or you were wrong in giving a well-formatted input string.

Comment: @revo Might have been somehow caching results, could also be the plugin. But I managed to clean everything up using the example anubhava gave. Thank you both for taking some time to try and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with negative lookahead:

```
<a (?:(?!(?:domain1|domain2)\.).)+?</a>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i2nGW4/2/)

Here `(?:(?!(?:domain1|domain2)\.).` is a negative lookahead that performs lookahead assertion before each character to make sure it is not `domain1` or `domain2.`.